# How ASP.NET Core 3.1 default authentication work?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I've created a new ASP.NET Core 3.1 MVC project with "Individual User Accounts" authentication.

If I run the app, and click on the "Register" link from the navbar, it redirects to: `https://localhost:44337/Identity/Account/Register`.

However, there is no controller called "Identity" or "Account", and no action is called "Register". I also can't find the "Model" that represents the user account. So, they seem to be lying somewhere in the ASP.NET Core source code.

So, here are concrete questions:

1. The default template operates directly on the database when registering new user. How can I make a "fake" class to avoid operating on the database while development, and easily get back to using the database later on?
2. How can I make modifications to the login and register views? There is no "Login.cshtml" or "Register.cshtml" or anything of that kind.
3. How to extend the user model capabilities, such as adding a field to "Date of birth" for example?

Answer (score 2):

The default pages you mention are 'built-in'.   If you want to override them, then you need to run scaffolding on the pages you wish to override.

To add scaffolded pages, right click on project/new scaffolded item/Identity/Add and you get this [image: page]

Tick the pages you want to override and it will generate them as source code for you.

Use .HasData to create seed entries in your database when you run migrations, as shown [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/data-seeding)

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Post>().OwnsOne(p => p.AuthorName).HasData(
   new { PostId = 1, First = "Andriy", Last = "Svyryd" },
   new { PostId = 2, First = "Diego", Last = "Vega" });
```

Comment: Great! But what about the point of not working on the database while development?
How can I somehow use DI to have a fake hard-coded users to work on?

Comment: Use seed data to populate your database with  test users when running migrations. See here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/data-seeding

Answer (score 1):

Regarding question 3, you can create your own user class which extends from IdentityUser:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
}
```

then register it in your ApplicationDbContext.cs:

```
public DbSet<ApplicationUser> Users { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need the check areas folder for that this class cshtml files all in there.